# ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename ansistyles -> .ansistyles.DELETE

Tags: cordova, npm, npm-install

I am getting an error when running `npm install`. It complains about not finding the module /node_modules/ansistyles... that folder does indeed not exist, but there is one with a dash: /node_modules/ansi-styles.

```
npm install
npm WARN helloworld@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansistyles
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansistyles' -> '/app/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.ansistyles.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /.npm/_logs/2018-02-01T13_20_48_203Z-debug.log
```

I also ran into the same error when running `cordova plugin remove` or `cordova plugin add`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Removing `package-lock.json` did the trick on my Mac!

Comment: That's worked for me. I was thinking that there might be possibility that that module does not exits any more but as soon as i removed package-lock.json and reinstalled it worked. Thanks

Comment: just delete node_modules and npm install fix it too